# Adding datatables from dynamic tabs into an arraylist

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, merge, datatable, copy

There are three tabs on the design of my page. In the third tab, there are dynamic tabs that are created. The number of tabs are based on the number of rows from the input file (which is in the first tab, for this case I will use two rows == two (dynamic) tabs in the third tab). 
This means there are two tables, one table (let's call it Table A) in the first dynamic tab and another table (let's call it Table B) in the second dynamic tab.

I am trying to add Tables A and B into an arraylist.

Currently I have the code;

```
For each page in Tabs.Tabpages
Dim dataTableToCopy as New DataTable
dataTableToCopy = dynamicDataTable.copy
arraylistToHoldTables.add(dataTableToCopy)
```

The issue with this is that it only copies the last data table, in this case Table B.

I have tried another method, in which involved merging the datatables.

```
For each page in Tabs.Tabpages
Dim dataTableToCopy as New DataTable
dataTableToCopy = dynamicDataTable.copy
mergedDataTable.Merge(dataTableToCopy)
arraylistToHoldTables.add(dataTableToCopy)
```

The problem with this method is that, although I am able to retrieve all values, the main task was to add each table into the arraylist. 
I was thinking of possibly splitting the merged datatable, but was unsure the method to take from there.

Split at row 100, since each table has 100 rows

Comment: Firstly, why are you using an `ArrayList` at all?  It's not 2004 any more.  If you want a collection containing `DataTables` then use a `List(Of DataTable)`.  Secondly, why do you create a new `DataTable` when you declare the `dataTableToCopy` variable and then immediately discard it?  You need to learn what the `New` keyword does and when you should use it.  If you don't want a new `DataTable` then don't create one.

Comment: As for the issue, that first code snippet is using the same `DataTable` to call `Copy` on every iteration of the loop.  `page` is the current `TabPage` so you need to get the `DataTable` associated with that page inside the loop, not use a variable that refers to the same `DataTable` the whole time.  In a `For Each` loop, if you're not using the loop control variable inside the loop then you are almost certainly doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to access each datatable from each tab was to iterate through the Controls of each tab

so in each tab, create a datagridview of the one in that tab and add that to the list.